# Incorporating the count values under unique values in Symbology in the Legend

Tags: arcgis-desktop

Is it possible to have the legend show the `count` values that are calculated in `Unique values` under `Symbology>Categories` in `ArcMap`? Please note the data is in `vector` format.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the count of the features displaying in the map in the legend by changing this legend property:

[image: Legend]

Note the values will adjust as you zoom in/out. Not sure you can have the totals that are displaying in the symbology tab where you build your symbols. To get those you need to be displaying the full dataset in your map.

Alternatively you can convert your legend to a graphic and edit the text but then you lose the live link between legend and data.